# Capybara+Rspec how to match a part of tag attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a page with several links like that `<a href='/bla/bla/bla/?page=xxx>text</a>`
I want to match certains `xxx` values links using Capybara and RSpec, i don't care about `bla/bla/bla` part of `href` attribute.

```
page.should have_selector("div.class ul li a", :href => "page=2")
```

doesn't work,
also

```
page.should have_xpath("//a[@href='page=2']")
```

is not an option because i don't know the full `href` attribute value.

PS: also didn't find any complete Capybara API documentation just to get all available methods and parameters' description. I there such thing?

Comment: Re. documentation, in the [Capybara readme.md](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) on Github, search for the section on "Finding." That section refers to the Rubydoc on [Capybara::Node::Finders](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders) for full reference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using `contains`:

```
page.should have_xpath "//a[contains(@href,'page=2')]"
```

Comment: thanks, that's what i was looking for, unfortunately capybara misses comprehensive documentation :(

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
link = page.find('div.class ul li a')
link[:href].should match(/page=2/)
```

More information [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element).

Comment: that finds the first element and checks its href, but i wand to match if there's any element

Comment: So you want to make two assertions then... first that the link you want exists and then that its href value contains /page=#{some_value}/. Also, I think that it's worth testing the existence for, it's worth giving an id. You shouldn't have to search for 'div.class ul li a')